# How to pass div's html to @Url.Action in Ajax post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jquery

## A. Where I am so far successfully:

1. I have 3 divs"
    NewAction
    NewController
    NewArea
2. I have an $.Ajax post with the url currently as follows
     '@Url.Action("CurrentAction", "CurrentController", new { area = "CurrentArea" })'
3. I have several pages that require this particular Ajax post so I put the Ajax post in a partial, and each main page that uses it, has a parameter in the partial call, eg:

   @Html.Partial("_PartialPage", new [] { "NewAction", "NewController", "NewArea" })
4. The divs in #1 above are successfully populated dynamically with the string values in #3

## B. Where my difficulty lies:

Despite many efforts & attempts, I cannot change the @Url.Action values in #2 to the values in the divs in #1.

I even tried to declare C# private variables and populate them with the foreach that populated the divs above and pass those values to the @Url.Action link, but I get a run error.

Does anyone know a way I can pass the parameter values in my partial call (#3) to the Url.Action method in the Ajax post in #2 above.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you show an example of the html of the divs? I'm having trouble understanding whats in your partial, and whats on the main pages.

Comment: @{ int i = 0;}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    i++;
    <div id="routeItem_@i">@HttpUtility.UrlDecode(item)</div>
}

Comment: I do not know why I post sometimes on this site. If you cannot get some help, you get lip service to a link with the comment "Read this". I mean why bother?

Comment: AF: I tried that as (vaguely) mentioned in para 2 of where my difficulty lies. I am going to review what Darin posted and comment back my results. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a method that will extract the values that are passed to this strongly typed partial and build the url:

```
@model string[]

@functions {
    public string GetUrl() {
        if (Model != null && Model.Length > 2)
        {
            var values = new RouteValueDictionary();
            values["controller"] = Model[0];
            values["action"] = Model[1];
            values["area"] = Model[2];
            return Url.RouteUrl(values);
        }
        return Url.Action("CurrentAction", "CurrentController", new { area = "CurrentArea" });
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(GetUrl()));    
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result) {
            // ...
        }
    });
</script>
```

will render like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "/NewArea/NewAction/NewController";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result) {
            // ...
        }
    });
</script>
```

But if you don't need those route values separately another possibility is to directly pass the entire url to the partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("_About", Url.Action("NewAction", "NewController", new { area = "NewArea" }))
```

and then inside the partial simply use it:

```
@model string
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));    
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result) {
            // ...
        }
    });
</script>
```